# Trying to make a request locally to dynamo db and getting this error `read server hello A: unknown protocol`

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to make a request locally to dynamo db with the aws client and I am getting this unknown protocol error, I have been trying to dig in this problem but cannot find any solutions that work, any pointers on how to tackle this would be great. The dynamo db is running locally on docker on port 8000

```
params = {:table_name=>"posts_development", :key=>{:uuid=>"41b75c2fbdd53ee13a590af8f99c0519", :post_uuid=>"41b75c2fbdd53ee13a590af8f99c0519"}, :consistent_read=>true}
dynamo_db_options = {:region=>"local", :http_read_timeout=>1}

aws = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(dynamo_db_options)
aws.get_item(params)


Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol
from /Users/sbinakhlaq/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
```

Comment: Where do you set URL for dynamo DB? What is the URL?

Comment: it is `https://localhost:8000`

Comment: try `http://localhost:8000`